# How can we apply filter in view for a content type by start date-time and end date-time?

Tags: views

I want to show the latest exam on a tablet based notice board. I am using Drupal 7.

For this I need to show an item from a content type called **Exams** which has a start date and end date with time. After the time ends I need to show the next item if there any.

We can apply start date and end date filter, but I want to check the time also.

For e.g.

> An exam starts on `28/01/2015 10:00 am and ends on 28/01/2015 11:30 am`.
>   If I will add another exam starts at 12:30 pm at the same day after the
>   first exam I need to show the second one automatically.

How can I accomplish this condition ? Seeking the help from Drupal experts.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) module, then just create a view with published exams.

> This module allows nodes to be published and unpublished on specified dates.
>
> Dates can be entered either as plain text or with calendar popups. To use calendar popups you need to install the Date Popup module, which is part of the [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module.

Comment: i don't have any date to enter.i need to show the exam from currently going.If the exam is 10.30 to 12.30 i need to show it. after that time it should not be visible. If there any other event between 1.30 to 2.30 it will also be shown after that.i need the condition to check if there is any event at the current time (now).